# How to re-render component after update data in store

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuex

I have a problem with re-render my `table` component when data in my `store` is updated,
I have a simply table with `v-for` like below:

```
<tr v-for="d in getDatas" v-bind:key="d.id">
```

and buttons to change page:

```
<button class="fa fa-chevron-left" @click="previousPage"/>
<button class="fa fa-chevron-right" @click="nextPage"/>
```

I load data to my datas before i open my component where is this table, and i get this data from store like below:

```
  computed: {
    getDatas () {
      return this.$store.getters.getDatas;
    }
  },
```

but how to update my store with `data` when i click on button `nextPage` or `previousPage`?
here is my methods:

```
  methods: {
      ...mapActions(["fetchDatas"]), //this is my action
      nextPage() {
        this.currentPage += 1;
      },
      previousPage() {
        if(this.currentPage != 1) {
          this.currentPage -= 1;
        }
      },
```

and my action:

```
    async fetchDatas({ commit },{ currentPage}) {
        const data = await fetch(`someURL&perPage=${currentPage}`);
        const response = await data.json();
        commit('setData', response);
    }
```

so, how to reload component and my store when i click on my `next/previousPage`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already have a `computed` property that automatically updates when your store updates.  All you have to do is trigger the action in your methods for changing pages.

```js
nextPage() {
   this.currentPage += 1;
   this.fetchDatas(this.currentPage);
},
previousPage() {
   if(this.currentPage != 1) {
      this.currentPage -= 1;
      this.fetchDatas(this.currentPage);
   }
},
```

And unless you have a compelling reason for requiring an Object parameter to the action, I would remove the curly braces entirely:

```js
async fetchDatas({ commit }, currentPage) {
...
```

Otherwise you need to call it with `this.fetchData({currentPage: this.currentPage})`.

Comment: I do it, but my component is still not reload with new datas (i saw that data is fetched properly) :(

Comment: try just replacing your computed with the actual getter in your store: `...mapGetters(['getDatas']),`

Answer (score 1):

You can setup a watch on the currentPagevariable where the getDatas action would be fired again on the change of the current page after clicking the buttons.

A watch can be declared as so:

```
watch: {
        currentPage: function (newValue) {
            this.$store.dispatch('fetchDatas', this.currentPage)
        },
}
```

Comment: hmmm, how to add parameter fo `fetchDatas` in `dispatch`? i ask because I must provide an argument to this action

Comment: Sorry missed that. You can add that like this: this.$store.dispatch('fetchDatas', currentPage)

Comment: oh, no matters, i have a bug in passing parameters to action, it work! thanks a lot!